# Simple Backup bash Script with nohup and rsync

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, backup, rsync

I have the following simple command to start my backup process in the background with nohup:

```
nohup rsync -a /src /target &
```

I am trying to find a proper solution to capture the exit code and send a failed or success message into a log file or mail. To achieve that I tried the following:

```
nohup rsync -a /src/ /target/ &
oldpid=$!
wait $oldpid

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
        echo "SUCCESS"
else
        echo "FAILED"
fi
```

The code seems to work fine but I acctually don't now if this is a reliable approach. I have two worries:

- Could the variable `$?` be overwritten when another command is executed in between?
- Is the `wait $oldpid` messing with the asynchronous way of nohup?

Or maybe this logic is just dumb and there is simply a better approach?

Comment: Are you using cron to run the rsync command? If so, have you considered using [chronic](https://github.com/docwhat/chronic) (and ensuring cron can send mail)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the question:

> ***Could the variable `$?` be overwritten when another command is executed in between?***

The answer is **YES**. The variable `$?` contains the exit status of the last task. For example:

```bsh
$ false; echo $?
1
```

```bsh
$ false; true; echo $?
0
```

```bsh
$ false; true; false; echo $?
1
```

Like as the variable `$!` contains the PID of the last background task.

Reference: [Devhints.io: Bash scripting cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/bash)

---

According to the question:

> ***Is the `wait $oldpid` messing with the asynchronous way of `nohup`?***

It shouldn't - isn't it designed exactly for such tasks? :)

---

According to the question:

> ***Or maybe this logic is just dumb and there is simply a better approach?***

For me it is not clear why you pushing the `rsync` into the *background* and then `wait` for it instead just execute the command and then do the test.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
rsync -a source.file destination.file 2>/dev/null

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo "SUCCESS"; else echo "FAILED"; fi
```

- `2>/dev/null` is used here to suppress the error messages of `rsync`, but you can save them in a temp file and attach it to the email.

But probably it is not the entire script...

---

In addition, in the first rows of `help wait` is provided the following information.

> wait: wait [-fn] [id ...]
>
> Wait for job completion and return exit status.

So you can use the output of `wait` directly within the `if` statement. I've already done successful test for this approach.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
nohup rsync -a source.file destination.file 2>/dev/null &
oldpid=$!

if wait $oldpid
then
        echo "SUCCESS"
else
        echo "FAILED"
fi
```

- `2>/dev/null` is used here to suppress the error messages of `nohup`, while `rsync` error messages goes somewhere in the background.